# How to vertically align text inside fixed-height list items using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I vertically align the text in the following list items:

http://jsfiddle.net/K2eF3/

```
<style>

ul { list-style-type: none; width: 300px; }
ul li { border: 1px solid red; height: 100px; }

</style>

<ul>
    <li>A bear</li>
    <li>A panda who eats bamboo</li>
    <li>A giraffe with a very very very very very veryvery very very very long neck</li>
</ul>
```

I can't use line-height because those sentences are dynamically generated and could be one line or multiline (not always singe). That's also why I can just individually target each `<li>` with custom padding.

Vertical align middle didn't work either, after reading up on it, it appears to only target elements which explains why aligning text inside an element using it didn't work.

Comment: [Vertically Center Multi-Lined Text](https://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)

Answer (score 24):

Wrap the content of each `<li>` in a `<span>` then apply the following css:

```
ul li span {
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/K2eF3/12/

Comment: Tables are so taboo :D

Comment: @Sorin because tables were what was used before CSS and the practice was supposed to be dropped :p

Comment: NOTE: `<span>` height = `<li>` height is very important for this fix to work.

Answer (score 2):

if you are not too worried about IE7 and below, try wrapping the text with a div and adding `display:table-cell`, `vertical-align:middle` and `height:100px` on the div.

Answer (score 1):

Safari/Chrome and Firefox have their own implementations of the [CSS Flexible Box Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/), which allows this sort of layout:

- http://jsfiddle.net/K2eF3/4/

However, there’s sadly no `display:-o-box;` or `display:-ms-box;` for Opera and Internet Explorer yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [my working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/K29Zj/).

It uses jQuery to vertically align the span inside the li. To make sure the span is correctly aligned it should have the display property should have inline-block value.

If you can't change the output to the spans inside the LI I can help you doing it using jQuery.